# A connection could not be establish to (LOCAL)

Tags: sql-server, connection, sql-server-2000, local

I am using SQL Server 2000. Yesterday I have installed IE11 on my PC. After the installation done, I found out that my SQL Server 2000 local connection is not working. Below are the error message I received.

[image]

I found a stop logo beside my server name as well.

[image]

I need guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue.

There is a lot of data inside this server.

Thanks

Comment: Start the SQL Server service! Also, SQL Server 2000? Wowzer!

Comment: @DavidG, I cant start. It shows access denied.

Answer (score 1):

The red icon shows that the SQL Server service is not running (probably).
Try right-clicking the red icon and selecting "Start". Wait a few seconds then try logging into SQL again.

Comment: it shows "connection failed,check sql server registration properties"